How to add column filters to the pivot sheet using FreeSpire.Xls package in .net c#
I am trying to add column filters in the pivot sheet using freespire.xls package.
But fiters dropdown option not getting displayed in the pivot sheet.
I need column filters for all the columns present in the pivot sheet.
**foreach (PivotField field in pt.ColumnFields)
 {
     field.IsAutoShow = true;
     field.SortType = PivotFieldSortType.Ascending;
 }**

